# How to get exit code when using Python subprocess communicate method?

Tags: python, subprocess

How do I retrieve the exit code when using Python's `subprocess` module and the `communicate()` method?

Relevant code:

```
import subprocess as sp
data = sp.Popen(openRTSP + opts.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

`Popen.communicate` will set the `returncode` attribute when it's done(*). Here's the relevant documentation section:

```
Popen.returncode 
  The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). 
  A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.

  A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).
```

So you can just do (I didn't test it but it should work):

```
import subprocess as sp
child = sp.Popen(openRTSP + opts.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE)
streamdata = child.communicate()[0]
rc = child.returncode
```

---

(*) This happens because of the way it's implemented: after setting up threads to read the child's streams, it just calls `wait`.

Comment: This example helped me, but it would be nice if examples didn't do the "import subprocess as sp" pattern of importing something standard as an obscure abbreviation. While this trims 8 characters off the code that follows it, it also makes it difficult to understand and reuse.

Comment: @uglycoyote There's no rule that says you have to copy and paste. Just retype it however you want, it's like 4 like lines.

Comment: @uglycoyote you could also edit it to be something like `from subprocess import Popen` and then just use `Popen` instead of `subprocess(or sp).Popen` which I'd say probably increases readability and shortens lines

Comment: Yeah... must call `process.communicate()` and then assign `returncode` to some variable. If the assignment is done before calling `communicate`, is `None`.

Comment: Is it possible to show the return code without redirecting the pipe? I am calling a bash code and I would like to see the output in real time in the terminal

Comment: @Nisba, the redirection is not required.

Answer (score 24):

Just to point out a common misconception, you should avoid `Popen` always when you can. To quote [the documentation,](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

> The recommended approach
> to invoking subprocesses is
> to use the [`run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function
> for all use cases
> it can handle.
> For more advanced
> use cases, the underlying
> [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) interface
> can be used directly.

If you just want to run a subprocess and wait for it to finish, that's a single line of code with `subprocess.run` or its legacy siblings `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.check_output`, and you don't need to copy/paste and/or understand the intricacies of the `communicate` and `wait` etc methods required around the low-level `Popen` object.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.run(
    [openRTSP] + opts.split(),
    capture_output=True,
    # avoid having to explicitly encode
    text=True)
data = proc.stdout
result = proc.returncode
```

If you don't want to capture the output from the process, maybe replace `capture_output=True` with `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` (and perhaps similarly for `stderr`); in the absence of either, the output will simply be displayed to the user, outside of Python's control.

Also, unless your options in `opts` are completely trivial, generally replace the regular string `split()` here with `shlex.split()` which understands how to cope with quoted strings.

Answer (score 21):

`.poll()` will update the return code.

Try

```
child = sp.Popen(openRTSP + opts.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE)
returnCode = child.poll()
```

In addition, after `.poll()` is called the return code is available in the object as `child.returncode`.

Comment: when I did this .poll() was empty.  I had to run child.communicate() in the line above child.poll() for this to work.

Comment: I think you meant to use .wait() instead of .poll(), as per documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html. Note that .wait() takes an optional timeout param which can be convenient.

Comment: [poll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)() will only update the return code if the child has terminated, otherwise it will return None - [wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)() is better here.

Answer (score 19):

You should first make sure that the process has completed running and the return code has been read out using the `.wait` method. This will return the code. If you want access to it later, it's stored as `.returncode` in the `Popen` object.

Comment: `.communicate()` already waits for the subprocess to terminate.

Answer (score 13):

Use `process.wait()` after you call `process.communicate()`. 
For example:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['ipconfig', '/all'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
exit_code = process.wait()
print(stdout, stderr, exit_code)
```

Answer (score 8):

[`exitcode = data.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait). The child process will be blocked If it writes to standard output/error, and/or reads from standard input, and there are no peers.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It also prints the output returned by the child process

```
child = subprocess.Popen(serial_script_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    retValRunJobsSerialScript = 0
    for line in child.stdout.readlines():
        child.wait()
        print line           
    retValRunJobsSerialScript= child.returncode
```

Comment: You can't meaningfully `wait` more than once.

Answer (score -2):

Please see the comments.

Code:

```
import subprocess


class MyLibrary(object):

    def execute(self, cmd):
        return subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True,)
      
    def list(self):
        command = ["ping", "google.com"]
        sp = self.execute(command)
        status = sp.wait()  # will wait for sp to finish
        out, err = sp.communicate()
        print(out)
        return status # 0 is success else error


test = MyLibrary()

print(test.list())
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\shita\Documents\Tech\Python>python t5.py

Pinging google.com [142.250.64.78] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.64.78: bytes=32 time=108ms TTL=116
Reply from 142.250.64.78: bytes=32 time=224ms TTL=116
Reply from 142.250.64.78: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=116
Reply from 142.250.64.78: bytes=32 time=139ms TTL=116

Ping statistics for 142.250.64.78:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 84ms, Maximum = 224ms, Average = 138ms

0
```

Comment: You can't `communicate` after `wait`.