# How to get the exit status set in a shell script in Python

Tags: python, shell, unix

I want to get the exit status set in a shell script which has been called from Python.

The code is as below

#### Python script

```py
result = os.system("./compile_cmd.sh")
print result
```

#### File *compile_cmd.sh*

```
javac @source.txt
# I do some code here to get the number of compilation errors
if [$error1 -e 0 ]
then
echo "\n********** Java compilation successful **********"
exit 0
else
echo "\n** Java compilation error in file ** File not checked in to CVS **"
exit 1
fi
```

I am running this code, but no matter the what exit status I am returning, I am getting result var as 0 (I think it's returning whether the shell script ran successfully or not).

How can I fetch the exit status that I am setting in the shell script in the Python script?

Comment: you can use subprocess and get the returncode, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```py
import subprocess

result = subprocess.Popen("./compile_cmd.sh")
text = result.communicate()[0]
return_code = result.returncode
```

Taken from here: [How to get exit code when using Python subprocess communicate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method)

Answer (score 15):

To complement [cptPH's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20347923/45375) with the recommended **Python v3.5+** approach using [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

```py
import subprocess

# Invoke the shell script (without up-front shell involvement)
# and pass its output streams through.
# run()'s return value is an object with information about the completed process. 
completedProc = subprocess.run('./compile_cmd.sh')

# Print the exit code.
print(completedProc.returncode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("Main.exe",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)
result,err = proc.communicate()
exit_code = proc.wait()
print(exit_code)
print(result,err)
```

In subprocess.Popen -> creation flag is used for creating the process in detached mode
if you don't wnat in detached more just remove that part.
subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS -> run the process outside of the python process

with proc.communicate() -> you can get he output and the errors from that process
proc.wait() will wait for the process to finish and gives the exit code of the program.

> Note: any commands between subprocess.popen() and proc.wait() will execute as usual at the wait call it will not execute further before the subprocess is finished.