# in a Python script, how to get a value from another Python installation?

Tags: python

I have two different installations of Python (one is inside a chrooted jail, one outside, and they have different versions).  From a Python script running with one of them, I need to call "the other Python" and get some internal value (sys.path).

I can use something like

```
subprocess.call("<the other python> -c 'import sys; print sys.path'", shell=True)
```

redirect it to a file, read it from there, etc.  but that seems convoluted, to go through IO like that.

Is there an easy direct way?

(Basically, I need to append sys.path from one Python to another Python's sys.path).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method

Comment: @matcheek thank you - yes I know of that, it's a similar idea to "call" - but is there a direct way, without having to capture stdout

Comment: You are talking about interprocess communication - https://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html

Comment: Maybe make it write its sys.path to a shared file and read from it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is not another more direct way. You're trying to capture run-time details from another process, so some kind of interprocess communication is necessary. The only way I can think of to get this information without running the other interpreter would be to do some very complicated parsing of configuration files and environment/shell variables, and probably also diving into the registry if you're on Windows.

I think you're much better off with a single (albeit long) one-liner:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

other_path = Popen("<other interpreter path> -c 'import sys; print sys.path'", 
                    stdout=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

At least with this method you're not writing anything to a disk, so you're bypassing one of the slowest IO methods.