# psutil/subprocess return code when process killed

Tags: python, psutil

I replaced some use of Python *subprocess.Popen* instances with *psutil.Popen* instances and expected the behaviour to remain the same.

The psutil docs for Popen state:

> *A more convenient interface to stdlib subprocess.Popen. It starts a sub process and deals with it exactly as when using subprocess.Popen but in addition it also provides all the methods of psutil.Process class in a single interface.*

I have found that the return code when terminating a process is not the same, as demonstrated by the sample below.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('sleep 100', shell=True)
>>> p.kill()
>>> p.wait()
-9
>>> 
>>> import psutil
>>> p = psutil.Popen('sleep 100', shell=True)
>>> p.kill()
>>> p.wait()
9
>>> 
>>> print sys.version
2.7.3 (default, Aug 28 2012, 13:02:46) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]
>>> print psutil.__version__
2.1.1
```

What are the POSIX guarantees on exit codes when a process is terminated? Are both the above return codes valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX exit codes have values 0-255. POpen's retcode isn't exactly the same as the process' exit code, in that POpen will sometines use the -ve code. The POpen docs are quite explicit as to when that can/will happen:

Ref documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode
Ref this question [How to get exit code when using Python subprocess communicate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method)

However, the psutil docs don't mention that at all:
https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Classes (see the `wait(timeout=None)` section).

I guess it's arguable as to which is 'correct', but if psutil is supposed to follow the same interface as POpen, then I think this is probably a bug/missing feature.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in psutil which I now fixed: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/960