# Need to get return code from cmd command of the below code using python

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, popen, windows-task-scheduler

This is the code that I want to run in cmd using python and I want it to return data with which I proceed in the program accordingly

```
SCHTASKS /query /TN TaskName >NUL 2>&1
```

As you can see, this code probably returns a false value if the TaskName is not found.

I want to get this data i.e: If the task does exist I need to get some error code back and need to get a different return code when it does exist.

I tried using

```
var=subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", "SCHTASKS /query /TN TaskName >NUL 2>&1"], shell = True)
print var
```

But this just gives me some object location in the memory presumably. Since this is using the help of cmd it seems to require a different syntax for returning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get exit code when using Python subprocess communicate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method)

Comment: NO, it seems different than others since cmd is involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `start` to start in the background, since you won't be able to get return code or output.

If you just want the return code of the command and hide output/error message, just create a `Popen` object then wait for task completion:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["SCHTASKS","/query","/TN","TaskName"],stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
return_code = p.wait()
```

Python 2 doesn't have `DEVNULL`, so you have to open a null stream manually ([How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess-in-python-2-7)):

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w')  as FNULL:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["SCHTASKS","/query","/TN","TaskName"],stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
    return_code = p.wait()
```

if you need to do that in the background, wrap the above code in a python thread. Also:

- Always pass your command line arguments as lists so the quoting (if needed) is handled automatically
- Don't use `start` as you lose control over the process & its return code.
- Don't use `shell=True`, since using `Popen` redirection to `DEVNULL` is more portable.

Comment: `DEVNULL` only works in python 3. Try without all redirection to see if it works for you. I'll edit later