# Popen Subprocess Python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen

I am using Popen to remote call script

```
s = Popen(['ssh' , ssh_argument0 , ssh_argument1 , '/tmp/remote/dude_rc_admsvr.sh %s %s' %(DomainHome , ACTIVITY)])
```

stdout = s.communicate()

print stdout

The script is not exiting with the status mentioned under shell script , instead it only prints success or failure status only ..

i want to exit with the status codes as per shell script.
here is shell script

```
tail -Fn0 ${ADM_DOMAIN_LOG} | \
while read LOG_LINE;
do
 echo ${LOG_LINE} | grep -q "${PASS_MSG}"
 if [ $? = 0 ]
 then
   echo "${STATUS_SUCCESS}"
   exit 0
 elif echo ${LOG_LINE} | grep -q "${FAIL_MSG}"
 then
   echo "${STATUS_FAILURE}"
   exit 1
 elif echo  ${LOG_LINE} | grep -q "${FAIL_MSG2}"
 then
    echo "${STATUS_FAILURE}"
    exit 1
 fi
done
exit
```

How to get the status code returned ?

Comment: Have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method

Comment: but my shell script is exiting with the status code , how come its not working when used in Popen

Comment: And the script is not even exiting atleast it should exit

Comment: In that case I would say write the status to a file and then read it from there , I know this is not the best way but it works

Comment: But the script is not even exiting the Popen command...

Answer (score 0):

From [`subprocess.check_call`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

> If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise
>   `CalledProcessError`. The `CalledProcessError` object will have the return
>   code in the `returncode` attribute.

Therefore, to get the status code, you need to catch the exception and retrieve the `returncode` attribute.

```
try:
    check_call(['ssh' , ssh_argument0 , ssh_argument1 , '/tmp/remote/dude_rc_admsvr.sh %s %s' %(DomainHome , ACTIVITY)]) 
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('status code = %s' % e.returncode)
```

Comment: But why its not taking the exit code from shell script , i have already added exit 0 , exit 1 to shell code

Comment: Yeah , Same issue its not exiting + echo '<Jun' 26, 2018 11:17:05 PM 'PDT>' '<Notice>' '<WebLogicServer>' '<BEA-000365>' '<Server' state changed to 'RUNNING>'
+ grep -q 'Server state changed to RUNNING'
+ [ 0 = 0 ]
+ echo P
+ exit 0

Comment: @user2900860 In what you just posted, the script appears to exit with 0, meaning success, so naturally `check_call` returns without raising an exception, and therefore won't go into the except block to print the status code. Did you try a scenario where the script returns 1 instead?

Comment: Its not even exiting with exit 1
grep -q 'Server state changed to RUNNING'
+ [ 0 = 0 ]
+ echo P
+ exit 1

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not even exiting"? Is the script not finishing? Did you make sure the script runs with the given arguments in command line first? Did you try using ssh to run the script in command line first?

Comment: Yeah i tried in the local unix box its exiting but via Popen(ssh) its not exiting ..

Comment: s = Popen(['ssh' , ssh_argument0 , ssh_argument1 , '/tmp/remote/dude_rc_admsvr.sh %s %s' %(DomainHome , ACTIVITY)]) 
 stdout = s.communicate()

 print stdout

Comment: But you question does not include `Popen` or `communicate()`. Please update your question with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new answer since you changed your code in question from using `check_call` to using `Popen` and `communicate`.

From [`subprocess.communicate`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s `stdin`, you need to
>   create the `Popen` object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than `None` in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE`
>   and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

In other words, you need to add `stdout=PIPE` to your call to `Popen`'s constructor in order to use `communicate`.

```
s = Popen(['ssh' , ssh_argument0 , ssh_argument1 , '/tmp/remote/dude_rc_admsvr.sh %s %s' %(DomainHome , ACTIVITY)], stdout=PIPE)
stdout = s.communicate()
returncode = s.returncode
```

Comment: the shell script is not exiting from popen ssh code , i dont care about the return code i just want to exit from the console/function

Comment: @user2900860 Try adding `input=PIPE` to the arguments as well. By the way you did stress that you want get the status code in your question (you said "How to get the status code returned ?"). Saying that you don't care about it now just contradicts yourself.

Comment: The script is not exiting with the status mentioned under shell script , instead it "only prints success or failure status only ."  thats what i mentioned above i need shell script exit status instead of popen ..

Comment: @user2900860 Did adding `input=PIPE` help?

Comment: resolved tail was holding ssh session which was reolved by adding kill -9 |`ps -eaf |grep tail`..

Answer (score 0):

Found Issue :

The tail statement in shell script was holding the SSH session which is why Popen couldn't able to exit the subshell , Adding kill -9 `ps -eaf |grep tail` resolved the issue.