# How to capture the output of exit()

Tags: python, exit, exit-code

I am working with code that my client insists cannot be changed. It needs to be called using a python command like subprocess.call() ... The code includes a use of the exit() function. When exiting, the exit() function contains data as a parameter:

```
exit(data)
```

How can I capture the data parameter that the script is using when calling exit() without modifying the code to use a return or anything like that?

Comment: It’s Python code?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is a valid exit code (i.e., a number in 0-127, I believe), then you can get the exit code via the `subprocess` API as the return value of the call function:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['python3', '-c', 'exit(24)'])
24
```

If it's not, then it will be printed out, so the easiest way is probably to capture the stderr of the process and parse it out of there.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs for `exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit):

> `exit(code=None)` ... when called, raise `SystemExit` with the specified exit code.

From the [docs for `SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit):

> If the value is an integer, it specifies the system exit status (passed to C’s `exit()` function); if it is None, the exit status is zero; if it has another type (such as a string), the object’s value is printed and the exit status is one.

So the answer depends whether `data` is an integer or not. If it is an integer, then it is the subprocess's exit code; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method) for how to get it from `subprocess`. If `data` is not an integer, then it's printed to stderr; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate) for how to get it from `subprocess`.

Comment: The value of the `SystemExit` exception is written to standard error (I edited that); the linked question describes how to capture standard output, though it should be easy to adapt to standard error instead.

Comment: @chepner Oh, of course. I assumed it would be stdout since the docs didn't specify stderr, but I should have checked. Thanks for fixing!