# Python subprocess and bash logical operator

Tags: python, bash, git, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to figure out how to handle a bash logical operator ('&&') in a Python subprocess.

The command, obviously works as expected on the terminal:

```
git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin/master
```

When I try this, I get an error saying C is an unknown switch:

```
subprocess.Popen(['git', '-C', repo_path, 'fetch', '&&', 'git', '-C', repo_path, 'diff', '--name-only', '..origin/master'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I'm sure I am missing something silly, but I can't find anything regarding how to handle the '&&' operator.

Thanks for your help

**Edit**

Thanks @heitor for pointing in the good direction.

Basically, Popen doesn't use shell operator by default, `shell=True` need to be added.

I'm still getting an git error, which might be related to the -C option. I'll work on this error tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: The answers on that page vary in how helpful they are, so to summarise - you would need to add `shell=True`, and for the command you use a string rather than a list of strings.  `subprocess.Popen("git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin/master", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Or use `communicate()` then check `.returncode` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method

Comment: The main point here is the need for `shell=True`. And when that is used, you need the command as a string. The linked page seems to suggest that you would still use a list for the command arguments, which I am led to believe would work under Windows but is not portable.

Comment: Although @user - what you are saying makes sense _if_ you clarify that it involves two separate `Popen` invocations.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) should do what you're after, assuming you're above python 3.5!

```
r = subprocess.run("git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin/master", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(r.stdout)
print(r.stderr)
```

I noticed that you'd added `-C` and prepended `repo_path` into your subprocess command, but these don't seem to fit the format of the original shell commands you were intending on using? Apologies if I've misinterpreted this, but I believe the above is what you're after based on the original shell commands and it solves your `&&` issue...

Good luck!